# How can I use array_map with keys and values, but return an array with the same indexes (not int)?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-map

I have an array such as `['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred']`.

I want to call `array_map` on this array and also use the key inside the function. However, when I make a return, my keys will become indexed.

Simple example :

```
$arr = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred');
$result = array_map(
    function ($value, $key) {
        return $value;
     },
     $arr,
     array_keys($arr)
);
var_dump($result);
```

Basically, I want `$result` to be identical to `$arr` in this case, but without reindexing my array.

Comment: You need to show what result you want.  This works as it should.

Comment: From the documentation "If the array argument contains string keys then the returned array will contain string keys if and only if exactly one array is passed. _If more than one argument is passed then the returned array always has integer keys_." (emphasis mine)

Comment: `array_map()` is an inappropriate tool for this job.  Show us what you actually want to do with this daya.

Comment: This question's problem statement is Unclear; therefor this page should be closed or edited by the asker.

Comment: `array_map()` does not kill keys if you just pass in the array. https://3v4l.org/HWH9C If you pass in multiple arrays, of course, it cannot know which keys to preserve. https://3v4l.org/KJbaV  This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329).

Answer (score 27):

For your requirement of "I want to call array_map" and "$result to be identical to $arr", try:

```
$result = array_combine(
     array_keys($arr), 
     array_map(function($v){ return $v; }, $arr)
);
```

Gives:

```
   [
     "id" => 1
     "name" => "Fred"
   ]
```

But heh, if all you want is identical arrays, then nothing beats this code:

```
$result = $arr;
```

Comment: This is not a good generic solution because the transformation function does not have access to the current key.

Answer (score 14):

The closest you will get using `array_map()` is this:

```
<?php
$arr = array('id'=>1,'name'=>'Jon');

$callback = function ($key, $value) {
    return array($key => $value);
  };

$arr = array_map( $callback, array_keys($arr), $arr);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Gives:

```
   [
     [
       "id" => 1
     ],
     [
       "name" => "Jon"
     ]
   ]
```

You will be better creating your own function with a `foreach` inside.

Comment: The question asks for original keys, not nested arrays with integer keys.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-walk.php).
Try this code:

```php
$arr = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Fred');
array_walk(
    $arr,
    function (&$value, $key) {
        // do stuff
    }
);
print_r($arr);
```

Unfortunately, it cannot change the keys but you can change the values if your callback uses them by reference.

If you have to change the keys too, check my other answer regarding [reindexing with `array_walk()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213966/2377961).

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Jannie Theunissen answer the correct way of getting an array_map working with key for comparing and assigning values based on second array for example is:

```php
$result = array_combine(
 array_keys($arr), 
 array_map(function($v, $key){ return $v; }, $arr, array_keys($arr))
);
```

Or for optimized alternative:

```php
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$result = array_combine(
 $keys, 
 array_map(function($v, $key){ return $v; }, $arr, $keys)
);
```

And with a comparison array value:

```php
$compareArray = [/*same structure as $arr but with specific values*/];
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$result = array_combine(
 $keys, 
 array_map(function($v, $key) use ($compareArray) { 
              // recursive can be achieved here passing $v and $compareArray[$key]
              return $compareArray[$key]; 
           }, $arr, $keys)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is quite simple. You need to use keys inside your array_map() function.

For this purpose we add two arrays: the first one `array_keys($array)` we pass the keys of our major array and the second one `$array` is the needed array.

```
array_map(function($key, $value) {

       // use your key here ...
       return $processed_value;

    }, array_keys($array), $array)
```

From now on: you can use the `$key` as a value from first param and `$value` as a second param.

Comment: it would be nice if you can add some explanation words to your solution

Comment: right you are. thanks for your comment.
i've updated my solution with description.

Comment: This returns an array with integer keys, which is the problem that is meant to solved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I came up with this, but I don't remember where I got it, either.

This function is generic, has the same variadic signature as `array_map()`, but preserves the keys of the first array passed, and the callback gets the current key as the first arg and the value(s) as the subsequent arg(s), like `function ($k, $v, $v2, ..., $vn) {`, (whereas `array_map()` only gets the array values).

```php
function array_map_assoc(callable $callback, array $array, array ...$arrays) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    array_unshift($arrays, $keys, $array);
    return array_combine($keys, array_map($callback, ...$arrays));
}
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/9XQF9

Other examples here have `function ($v, $k) {` as the callback signature but they're limited to one input array, and it doesn't make sense to have the key in the middle of the values when accepting multiple input arrays.